# XPosed: IXposedHookZygoteInit vs IXposedHookLoadPackage

Tags: android, hook, xposed

I'm using `XPosed` for hooking some methods on Android device. As I know, `IXposedHookZygoteInit` will run first when zygote process first starts. After that `IXposedHookLoadPackage` will be called when normal packages load.

So `IXposedHookLoadPackage` always run after `IXposedHookZygoteInit`. So my question is:  all my hook methods (including normal app or system app) can go to `IXposedHookLoadPackage` without any problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Thats the basic meaning of those methods